# Stop prompt from Gimp to save image

Tags: ubuntu-mate, gimp

Can I get rid of the prompt that Gimp gives when you want to exit without saving?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is meant to protect yourself. In pre-2.8 versions, you could do a lot of editing involving creating layers, selections and paths, "save" as JPG/PNG, and then exit without getting a prompt and oops... all the editing has to be redone from scratch. I have seen grown men cry :) which is why Gimp now distinguishes "save" and "export" and will warn you if the image hasn't been "saved".

Of course you can train your fingers to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. But someday you'll cry...

Comment: That's logical.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: how do I turn off the prompt? All this does is tell you why you shouldn't.

Comment: @Lelanthran You aren't allowed to. The configuration option to do so was [removed](http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/gimp-2.8-understanding-ui-changes) in 2012.

Comment: Wow, that's awful of Gimp to not allow you to make it shut up. If I had a need to keep all that metadata nonsense, I wouldn't be saving to a format that doesn't support it in the first place.

Comment: @Ocean The problem is that in images there is a confusion between an "edit" format (XCF....) and "publish" one (JPG, PNG), because you can edit the "publish" format. But if you see the two as clearly distinct (like DOCX/XLSX, and PDF), then the current behavior makes sense. It Excel, exporting to a PDF isn't saving the spreadsheet.

Comment: @xenoid I don't really have a use for an "edit" format. I open a picture, I do stuff to it, I save the picture. Now I am done forever with this picture. It is unfortunate that Gimp doesn't allow for this workflow to be convenient.